# Failed to resolve component: amplify-s3-image , but it actually works

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I get this warning in my Chrome Console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: The `compilerOptions` config option is only respected when using a build of Vue.js that includes the runtime compiler (aka "full build"). Since you are using the runtime-only build, `compilerOptions` must be passed to `@vue/compiler-dom` in the build setup instead.
```

and then this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: amplify-s3-image
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

But the component actually works, since it shows the image from S3 how it's supposed to.

This is what my main.js looks like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue' 
import router from './router'
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import AmplifyVue from '@aws-amplify/ui-vue';
import store from './store'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components/loader';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
//Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
    defineCustomElements(window);
  });


const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(store).use(AmplifyVue)
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('amplify-');
app.mount('#app');
```

and this is in my vue.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true
  },
)

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
      config
          .plugin('html')
          .tap(args => {
              args[0].title = "Opensquare";
              return args;
          },options => {
            options['compilerOptions'] = {
              ...options.compilerOptions || {},
              isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('amplify-')
            }
            return options;
          })
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It's not blocking, since the component actually works, but reading the Console with this WARN popping up is a nightmare.